# Get non-integers from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I create a regex for that returns true if it has only numbers and '+' basically `0-9 & +`. Using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: What is your understanding of regexes and using them in JS, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Regex for plus anywhere: `/^[0-9+]+$/`
- Regex for plus only infront: `/^\+?[0-9]+$/`

What it does:

- `^` Matches the beginning of the string
- `[0-9+]` Matches `0123456789+`
- `+` Matches one or more
- `$` Matches the end of the string

Other version:

- `\+?` Matches zero or one plus signs in the front

Maybe try [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/) for future regex development.

How to test in code:

```
function isOnlyNumber(str) {
  return /^[0-9+]+$/.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Le the `+` before number regex is definitely useful